Troubleshooting HTTPS Issues with .NET Application on IIS Server
i have a IIS Server with all installed bundles and co ...
If i run the build locally https works and on server there is nothing. Via PortScanner i see it opened port and EventManger shows me process started.
Via http i can see all and it works there but not on https.
i have on same IIS same ssl certificate the frontend with vue3 and it works fine...But not the .net app here...Where the hell is my mistake?
Program.cs
using BaseBackend.Controllers;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(); // For MVC support
builder.Services.AddControllers(); // For API support

// Configure Swagger/OpenAPI
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Register IConfiguration for DI
//builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(builder.Configuration);

// Register TuningDatabaseHandler for DI
builder.Services.AddScoped<TuningDatabaseHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyUploadedFileHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<StringReplacementHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<TaskHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<EcuHandler>();



// Configure Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/api/login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/api/logout";
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;

    });

// Configure Authorization
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

// Configure CORS
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowFrontend", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost")
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowCredentials();

    });
});

builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.HttpsPort = 44390; // Specify the HTTPS port where is same in IIS
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

// Enable CORS policy
app.UseCors("AllowFrontend");

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// Use authentication and authorization middleware
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Test Page: Application is Running!");
app.Run();

appsettings.json
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
      "Swagger": {
        "Enabled": true
      },
      "ConnectionStrings": {
        "dbo": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Database=dbo;"
      },
      "Kestrel": {
        "Endpoints": {
            "Https": {
                "Url": "https://localhost:44390" // Set HTTPS to listen on port 44390
          }
        }
    }
}


44390? HTTPS sites on modern IIS versions should be on port 443.

but its not the port issue...i tried differnt ones

It's not surprising that multiple mistakes can be made the same time. After fully switching to port 443, run a report and see what else is broken, https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics

but i want my frontend to be on port 443 which would make more sense at all.i have frontend and backend on same server. or is this usually done in a different way?

Anyway The issue is Not the Port settings

And additional iis dont Allow two Apps on Same Port

Okay I did the strangest thing ever.
I added new project in my project in visual studio and added same template as before. Copied all files 1:1 to new one and deployed it. IIS now working on HTTPS.
Will never know what the issue was. Kestrel is also same as before.

I just created the basic ASP.NET Core MVC project and deployed it to IIS and it is viewable through the port you mentioned, and without any modifications. Like this:

In addition, I found that you have some setting related to Kestrel, I'm not sure where you used it. As far as I know, it maybe something wrong. In documation, it says : In production, a TLS certificate must be explicitly configured. At a minimum, a default certificate must be provided.
If you want to configure it in code, it should be something like:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
{
    serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
    serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 44390, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps("yourcert.pfx", "yourassword");
    });
});

